# Get direct link google drive

Tags: video, streaming

I would like to get direct links to my videos on google drive, as this site http://brafoz.com/t4hgbn0cgf5dcv54g7fgddf4g8f/

it has links like:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9nDWfAtO1JvugualUY7ZtjW-tcKAPN0jCu6ZOtW410eD50bLrZnkM5Z5JOBUwUeqEAAWUg=m22

or end exchange for better or worse quality ...

how to get such links? thank you